# MITMPROXY on router

Tags: man-in-the-middle, dns, proxy, router

I am familiar with MITM LAN attacks using dnsspoof and arpspoof to read client data.  Instead of spoofing the DNS and impersonating the router on my physical machine, I want to set up a MITM LAN attack through the router by changing the DNS and port forward rules. My goal is to decrypt all HTTP, HTTPS, and SSL traffic of each client connected to the router.  To accomplish this, I plan on using mitmproxy, sslsplit, and dnschef.

Currently I am having trouble forwarding the DNS requests in dnschef to mitmproxy.

Here is my set up

Attacker IP = 1.2.3.4

commands on attack machine:

```
dnschef -i 1.2.3.4 --fakeip 1.2.3.4
```

---

Changed router DNS server to 1.2.3.4

How do I set up the port forwarding rules for mitmproxy, sslsplit, and dnschef?

Comment: Obligatory "what have you tried so far"? This will depend on your router, but any guide on setting up mitmproxy as "transparent proxy" should be good as long as the OS matches. For example steps 3 and 4 of https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-transparent-vms/

Comment: If HTTP(S) traffic is already passing through the router, you would not need to manipulate DNS at all in order to intercept that traffic on the router.

Comment: I attempted to use webmitm to forward all HTTP/HTTPS traffic to another host running Burp Suite to capture the traffic instead of using mitmproxy.  dnschef works as it should with the current setup displayed above.  When I use webmitm -d 192.168.1.8 (burp suite host) it guides me through the creation of the webmitm.crt and then I receive this error:
webmitm: error:140AB18F:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate:ee key too small: Cannot assign requested address